# PHP socket server doesn't react to client connections on my shared hosting account

Tags: php, sockets, shared-hosting

On my shared hosting account in the public_html directory I have a php file that contains code for creating a socket server.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);             
$ret = socket_bind($sock, 'localhost', 80);             
$ret = socket_listen($sock);           
$msgsock = socket_accept($sock);

socket_write($msgsock, " hello");
?>
```

When I open that php file with a browser or run it as a command, the socket server waits for a client connection and after that the code should send "hello" to the client and finish executing. I know that the actual socket server must have a loop in it, so that it can work properly, but this code is just for testing. Also in the public_html I have a php file which is a client,

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$mysocket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);             
$result = socket_connect($mysocket, 'localhost', 80);               
if ($result === false) { 
echo "error"; 
} else { 
echo "successfully connected"; 
} 

$input = socket_read($mysocket,1024);
echo $input;
?>
```

and when I open it in a browser, it successfully connects to localhost on port 80 even if the php server file is not running. But when the php server file is running and waiting for a client connection, it continues to run even after the client file successfully connects to localhost, although without receiving "hello". When I try the same thing on my computer using apache server and run those files from another computer through the Internet, it works, that is the server file accepts the client, sends "hello" and finishes executing. So, what could be the reason why the php socket server doesn't react to client connections on my shared hosting account?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a port other then 80 to listen on. Its probably failing to create the server because the webserver is running on port 80.

Comment: It is allowed to use only ports 80 and 443 on shared hosting accounts. Besides, apache server on my computer is also running on port 80 and 443, and the code works there properly. And when I check socket_create, socket_bind and socket_listen functions without using socket_accept on my hosting account like this `if (($ret = socket_listen($sock)) < 0) { echo "error "; } else { echo "OK "; }`, it says "OK" on each function.